# Word: How to paste formatting from image to image?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

Say I have an image A. I paste it to Word, resize it, crop it, make border, change the wrap setting, etc. Then I find picture B will be more suitable.

How can I paste A's formatting from A to B? I don't want to do that again. I use Word 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as nothing too drastic has changed in Word 2013 you can right click on the image and choose "Change Picture" to replace the current picture with a new one while keeping the same formatting.

Comment: Stupid me. How can I forget that? Thank you so much :D